# Relative path variables in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

If I have an .htaccess file in a given directory within my website, and want to specify an ErrorDocument relative to the .htaccess file, NOT relative to the document root, is this possible?

Something like:
ErrorDocument 404 $CURRENT_DIRECTORY/404.php

Comment: NO -- documentation clearly shows what can be used as a value there and no variable parsing/replacement is performed: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Perhaps off-topic: why doesn't Apache ever get its limitations fixed? It needs relative addressing, local variables, a way to print a value to the browser or to the log file, using a PHP file for error handling instead of a long list of ErrorDocument directives and lots more fairly minor improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a number of directives are sensitive to relative directory while within an `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` context, `ErrorDocument` is not.  Per the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "master" 404.php that's used for all 404s, then within that file include the specific 404.php using a path determined by the request, an environment variable (set with [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)), etc.